# How to redirect the users to their id specific urls/landing pages after they log in?

Tags: php, redirect, login-control, login-script

How to redirect the users to their id specific urls/landing pages after they log in? The redirected urls' query strings should show values associated with their ids (Primary key) stored in Mysql database.

**For instance,**

The corresponding values of "id" for 1st, 2nd 3rd and 4th users are 1, 2, 3 & 4

The logged pages / landing pages should look like the following urls respectively after the users are looged in successfully.

www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=1

www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=2

www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=3

www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=4

*The log in session of the log in script is as following:***

// this sets session and logs user in**

```
session_start();
```

**//prevent against session fixation attacks.**

```
   session_regenerate_id (true);
```

**// this sets variables in the session**

```
$_SESSION['user_id']= $id;  
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $full_name;
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    **//update the timestamp and key for cookie**
    $stamp = time();
    $ckey = GenKey();
    mysql_query("update users set `ctime`='$stamp', `ckey` = '$ckey' where id='$id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**//set a cookie**

```
  if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
              setcookie("user_id", $_SESSION['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
              setcookie("user_key", sha1($ckey), time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
              setcookie("user_name",$_SESSION['user_name'], time()+60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
               }
               header('Location: user.php');
     }
    }
    else
    {
    //$msg = urlencode("Invalid Login. Please try again with correct user email and password. ");
    $err[] = "Invalid Username Or Password.";
```

What header I should use to redirect the users that way? Also, how to create the landing page for the same purpose.

Any help shall be well appreciated.

Comment: you are using header('Location: user.php); that 1) is a syntax error 2) doesn't even try to use the id.. also why would you want to get the user id from get if you have it stored in your session?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

The header shall be actually ('Location: user.php');

It was a typing mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append the user id from your `$_SESSION` to the URL you're redirecting to.

```
header('Location: user.php?id=' . $_SESSION['user_id']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is the perfect solution of the problem.
What shall be header if I want to associate the urls with the unique key values of the users?

Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking for a successful log in, return the user's id in your query.  Here's some quick pseudocode:

- In query: Select user_id where user_name = ? and password=?
- If results.count = 1 then store the user_id as $user_id
- Redirect to "www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=" . $User_Id

Comment: Your explanation isn't clear to me. Would you clarify? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to redirectjust like this :-

www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=1

then only do

```
header("Location: user.php?id=".$userId);
```

Comment: The syntax can retrieve the string key only but not the value from the database stored during the log in session
which is something like www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=

Many thanks.