# How to change a static navigation system to a PHP dynamic navigation system?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, navigation, login-script

How to change a static navigation system to a PHP dynamic navigation system for navigating to dynamic urls from other static urls?

For example,

The following session variable based login redirection header redirect the authenticated user to the landing page lnked with his ID value stored in Mysql database where ID is primary key and that has the corresponding value 1.

```
header('Location: user.php?id=' . $_SESSION['user_id']);
```

The above header redirect the user to the following dynamic url,

```
www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=1
```

where there is a navigation menu like,

```
<a herf="user.php"> User Account</a>
<a href="setting.php">User Setting</a>  
<a href="profile.php">User profile</a>
<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

Here the navigation link,

```
<a herf="user.php"> User Account</a>
```

itself is the static landing link / page of user who has been redirected to the following dynamic link / page after successful login,

```
www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=1
```

Now, how the respective user navigate to the link,

```
www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=1
```

but not to

```
www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php
```

from the other navigation links like,

```
<a href="setting.php">User Setting</a>
<a href="profile.php">User Profile</a>
```

Also, how shall I change the following static navigation links,

```
<a herf="user.php"> User Account</a>
<a href="setting.php">User Setting</a>  
<a href="profile.php">User profile</a>
```

to session variable based dynamic links associated with the corresponding ID value of the authenticated users so that the absoulte links look like,

```
www.anysite.com/anydirectory/user.php?id=1
www.anysite.com/anydirectory/setting.php?id=1
www.anysite.com/anydirectory/profile.php?id=1
```

since all the static links are about an authenticated user only?

Note: you can check the login session at [How to redirect the users to their id specific urls/landing pages after they log in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504539/how-to-redirect-the-users-to-their-id-specific-urls-landing-pages-after-they-log/8504609#8504609)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should not base your authentication on ID set in get. This can easily be changed or removed.

You recommend you write the following logic in your code:

1. You log successfully in
2. Id, password and some clever security-stuff is set in a cookies (or session)
3. On every pageload you check if the cookies (or session-variables) are valid
4. If they are invalid you force the user to login again
5. If it's valid, you already have the user-id.

You should only append a user-id in the url if you want the user to "visit" another user's profile or page. At facebook profile.php will point to your profile, while profile.php?id=111 will point to the profile with id 111. You don't want a user to be able to visit everyone's setting-page?

Comment: Well, looking at your other question, you have both a session and a cookie with the same user_id

Comment: Well, the authication process isn't based on the id session only. The process is involved couples of session and cookie based security measures. The existing process can store the user ids in the database but I want to append the key-value pair based on primary key (In this case id) in the url so that the respective users can bookmark the links, if they feel necessary, thoug they are able to log in through a particular log in page.

Comment: They will still be able to bookmark the links. This is how truly dynamic pages are made.

Comment: How, when the dynamic urls haven't any particular query string and value?

Comment: Well, imagine the following. A user bookmarks his setting-page settings.php?id=20. He logs out and another user takes over the computer. If he logs in and clicks the bookmark, he will get an error, because he is not id=20. I am saying it again, don't use id in GET to chose the userID, use session and cookie-varaibles.

Comment: I guess you haven't checked the header of login script carefully. The session variable based header syntax of login script redirects the authenticated user to dynamic urls where it pulls out both the query key (Here primary key is "id") and corresponding value of the users from mysql database stored during the log in session.

So, the values of key for all users won't be same at all.

Comment: At present situation the users can bookmark the landing pages only from where they can navigate to the other pages but they won't be able to bookmark all other pages independently those they navigate from the landing page. Yes, my question is about how can I change the static navigation menu to a dynamic nagivation menu using session variable toward the dynamic links since most often users delete the cookies from cache (The cookies are not functional in such case unless they relod or refresh the page) to speed up the performance of machine?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem finally. I'm posting the solution here so that it may become a guideline to the other viewers.

It can be done by echoing / querying the predefined PHP variavles like form variable & session variable, etc. as the value of primary or unique key (Here 'id' is both primary key and a unique key by default) inside the herf tag.

```
<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">User Account</a>
<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">User Setting</a>
<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']; ?>">User Profile</a>
```